# Why was Notification Hubs output binding removed from Azure Functions 2.x?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-notificationhub

The option to use Notification Hubs to send notification as an output of an Azure Function was removed from 2.x version. You can see in the table [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions#bindings) that the Notification Hubs output binding is only supported by 1.x version.

Why is that? What is the reason/motivation behind this decision?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should ask Microsoft, open an issue on the azure functions git repo.

Comment: The default github issue text indicated to me that the forum and stack overflow should be used for this question and github issue should be created for actual issues. So I rather created a question on the forum as well: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/30e86e5a-1783-42a7-a109-71f337f810fc/why-was-notification-hubs-output-binding-removed-from-azure-functions-2x?forum=AzureFunctions

Comment: is more a place to share coding problem that other people can asnwer as well but I know it is not obvious ;-) hope oyu ll get your answer

Comment: Were you able to get answers?

Comment: @RaasMasood Yes! Check the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this GitHub thread [Migrate NotificationHubs extension project](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/issues/239).

Azure Function 2.0 was busy preparing to be GA(released on 09/24/2018).
[Notification Hub SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs/2.0.0) was still in preview when Function team intended to support NH binding hence they didn't plan to add it with preview SDK in a GA Production.

After stable NH SDK is released on 09/13/2018, without enough time they may have to announce NH binding is N/A in Function 2.0.

Now both of them has been stable and Function team is working on it.

Comment: So it was basically just matter of time. Good to know! Probably then this will be supported in the not too distant future. Thanks for the answer! Feel free to post this answer here as well, so I can accept it as an answer: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/30e86e5a-1783-42a7-a109-71f337f810fc/why-was-notification-hubs-output-binding-removed-from-azure-functions-2x?forum=AzureFunctions

Comment: @Akos Thanks, could you post it as I am way from my pc.